Can enemies roll in Elden Ring?
I think I’ve noticed some humanoid enemies roll out of the way of a hit (not dodge out of the way), but I’m not sure.
Can they roll? What enemies can roll (if too many to give a list on, but can be divided into groups, say something along the lines of “all humanoid enemies, minus x”)? Do they get I-frames from this? And if so, the same amount of I-frames as the player? Finally, are they burdened by weight (too heavy armour results in a burdened roll, wearing almost nothing results in fast roll, etc)?

Most enemies in Elden Ring cannot dodge-roll and get i-frames like a player can.
Many enemies do have a dodge that they can do to avoid ranged attacks, but it doesn't give i-frames.
The exception to this rule is player-model NPCs.  These are NPCs and enemies that use the same skeleton and animation set as a player character.  Most NPC invaders and a handful of bosses (as well as a few non-boss enemies) fall into this category.  Since they use the same animation set as the player they can roll and get i-frames just like you can.  In fact, since they don't have a stamina meter they tend to spam roll more than you can as a player.  They technically don't get burdened by equipment weight (i.e. if you mod the game to give them heavier equipment they will keep the same roll speed), but they generally have roll speeds that align with their apparent equipment weight.
